# What protocols are supported for VoIP on iOS?

Tags: ios, protocols, sip, voip

My colleagues have developed a web-based (RTC) VoIP app and I am now going to develop the iOS counterpart. However, after researching the forums, I have found several limiting factors with the iOS:

-No support for RTC

-SIP must use Mac WiFi Solution DNS64/NAT64 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47658

Are there any other limitations that I should be aware of? What are the recommended protocols for developing a VoIP app for iOS?

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked on WebRTC for mobile. There are many works like Twillio,OOYOO, QuickBlox (http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios) etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limiting factor with iOS to develop VOIP based app.

Well, about notifying user ( iOS User ) about incoming VOIP call in background / kill state, you need to handle with push kit ( Silent push notification ).

About users are online / offline, it would be better to get flag from sockets, not from API call each time.

Let me know if i could help you any more in VOIP based app.